# Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using html5 `Canvas` to get colors from image. For this i wrote the following code in javascript :

http://jsfiddle.net/8dQSS/1/ (Pls check the console to see the exception)

```
function getImageColor() {
    var colors = [];
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        // Draw the image in canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        // Get the pixel data
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Loop through imageData.data - an array with 4 values per pixel: red, green, blue, and alpha
        for (var x = 0; x < imageData.width; x++) {
            for (var y = 0; y < imageData.height; y++) {
                var index = 4 * (y * imageData.width + x);
                var r = imageData.data[index];
                var g = imageData.data[index + 1];
                var b = imageData.data[index + 2];
                var a = imageData.data[index + 3];

                colors.push("rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")");
            }
        }
    };
    image.src = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/demos/assets/image.jpg";
}
```

The above code is throwing the following exception :

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

Can anybody please tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Don't use images from other domains, whose content you are not allowed to access?

Comment: Maybe it will help to diagnose (it's an old post): I have this error from a canvas I have generated myself from a data URI created from an SVG element, without any images. Works on FF and Safari just fine.

Comment: I'm getting this from an image I created dynamically with JavaScript from an SVG element, and pass as a data URI. It's a pain, then saying: "Uncaught SecurityError: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent." Chrome trying to be too clever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I know is to have the image you want to load hosted on the same server as your files, you can't access and handle any image you want on the web through your canvas.

EDIT : If you want you can do [like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CORS_Enabled_Image).

Answer (score 11):

Are you using this through file system .? If yes then run it on the server(localhost).

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error. I searched a lot about `crossorigin` on canvas. The first solution was add the `img.crossOrigin='anonymous'`. But the problem  still remains. I was using assets served by s3, and fixed the problem adding this on the bucket policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
         "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::seu-candidato/*"
     }
  ]
}
```

The assets from bucket had some params like `X-Amz-Expires`, `X-Amz-Date` I removed them and my problem ws fixed