# HTML5 - Image blur with stackblur

Tags: html, image, blur

I am trying to use stackBlur (http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) to blur entire image with `stackBlurImage( 'srcimg', 'canvas', 10, false );`. But neither it's working on local system nor on internet. Could someone please suggest me correct way of doing it?

Here is my jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yesprasoon/3KxrW/

Or please let me know any other way of blurring the image. CSS transition is not working in Phonegap for Android webkit.

**UPDATE**

Image was not getting blurred due to some '..because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data' error. I was testing it as local file in Chrome. Script runs fine with chrome:localhost/IE9/FF.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are not allowed to access and modify an image (with a canvas), unless it is hosted on the same server as your webpage.

See **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438377/unable-to-get-image-data-from-canvas-because-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cros)** for more details.

If the image is hosted alongside the webpage, then there is no problem using the code you provided (e.g. `stackBlurImage("srcimg", "canvas", 5, false);`).

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/rm3xK/)**.

Comment: I used an image url to display it on jsfiddle. In my local files I am using '<img id="srcimg" src="img/status/status_images-generic.png">'. What could be the problem?

Comment: I can't tell, if I don't see for myself. Is this publicly available ?

Comment: I'll try to make it public. I don't get that alert in my local files. Just to confirm - my problem is not 'can not access image' alert - but my problem is that it is not getting blurred. Am I writing correct code to blur with stackBlur?

Comment: Thanks! I was facing problem as I was using Chrome. There was some error in DevTools like '..because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data'. In IE9 and FireFox everything was fine.

Comment: Is the problem solved now ? Or is it still not working in Chrome ?

Comment: If it does not work in Chrome then it is not solved :) I tried my demo above in Chrome and it works fine. What does not work for you ?

Comment: Well as I had updated the answer earlier - it works in IE/FireFox normally. Also, it works in Chrome Localhost (http://localhost/). But it does not work in Chrome locally (file:///) - and I was testing it in Chrome and that too locally. When I tested the same by putting my files into localhost - it worked fine. It works fine with Phonegap and webView as well. Just to repeat - it works correctly with IE/FF locally (i.e. without localhost).